# MathJax doesn't work anymore in questions

Tags: bug, mathjax

Only very recently, I noticed that MathJax does not work correctly in questions.
For instance, set brackets are not displayed any more:

$\{1 \}$

If I post the same as an answer, it works correctly.
There are several other examples.
Before I never had this problem.

What happened?

Comment: Oh, in the published question it is displayed correctly. So, the bug might appear in the preview, only. Then, of course, it's just annoying, but not really a problem.

Comment: If you experience the bug only in the preview, the tag ([meta-tag:markdown-preview]) might be suitable here. And probably it would be good to include a screenshot - so that other can see what you saw (if they cannot reproduce the same bug).

Comment: I am not sure, but perhaps these past questions are about a similar problem: [\{, \}, \| and \\ need an extra backslash to be rendered correctly in math when composing a new question in MSE.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/35974) and [MathJax preview works incorrectly in Google Chrome.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/35946)

Comment: @Martin Slezak: yes, I think at least the first one is the same. I'm using Firefox, so the second one might be different. BTW: was this (sorry to call so) bug always there? Never experienced it before. Will math.stack.exchange repair it?

Comment: Curly brackets have always been used in $\LaTeX$ to delimit arguments to various typeset constructions.  So literal display of curly brackets has always required escaping them with backslashes in the MathJax display environment, e.g. for set builder notation.

Comment: @hardmath: yes, of course, I escaped the curly brackets with "\". And only in the preview, they were not displayed. Hence, my syntax was correct! The problem is the preview of math.stack.exchange.