Has something changed on latex?
Has something changed on latex?
In my browser, I cannot see curly braces with "backslash" "opening curly brace" any more.
Example below: I don't see curly braces. But I DO SEE CURLY BRACES in the text where I have copied it from!
${\displaystyle A\times B=\{(a,b)\mid a\in A\ {\mbox{ and }}\ b\in B\}}$;
What's wrong?

Please add more detail to your question.  Please show a screenshot.  Please describe what browser you are using (including version number), which operating system, and any extensions.  Please explain whether you are seeing this in preview mode or after the question is posted, and whether you are writing this in a question, answer, or comment.  Please explain how you copied it: did you copy-paste from the Mathjax/Markdown, or copy-paste from the formatted text.

Might this be related to https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/35946/14578 or https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/35974/14578?

Well, after the edit of D. W it works. What was my mistake?

O, no, even if I copy the whole thing to a new question, I don't see any curly braces! I don't want to commit it just to see if the braces miraculously show up.

I'm using firefox, via ubuntu, which urges updates via snap frequently ... even worse than microsoft, if anyone asks my opinion. Would it be OK if I really post something just to see if it looks just as bad after?

If you mean that you don't see the braces in the preview while composing a question, then I have recently answered this in detail for another post that asks basically the same question.
The upshot is that recent changes to the question editor have removed the code that protects the mathematics from being processed for Markdown commands, and so \{ and \} become { and } (since Markdown converts a backslash followed by a non-alphanumeric character into just that character without the backslash, preventing the usual action of that character in Markdown).
Unfortunately, there is no easy workaround, as the server-side processing of the final post still uses the math-protection code, producing a serious inconsistency between the preview and the final post.
One approach some are using is to use the answer editor (which still has the math-protection code) to compose their question, and then copy and paste into the question when you are ready to post.  A pain, but perhaps the easiest solution.
